# Contet type in PHP Mail

Tags: php

I have write a code to send a mail, the mail has send but the content of the mail is send as HTML coding, can anybody help to solve this problem.

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1" 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
```

This is the content type I have used.

Thankyou

Comment: Paste your code here please.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is to send email as plain text, than `Content-Type` must be changed to `text/plain` instead of `text/html`

Comment: Hi justinas, i am receiving the mail content like --PHP-alt-ef143f2b9bd8b6d17497bff2871af68e
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Hello World!!!
This is simple text email message.

--PHP-alt-ef143f2b9bd8b6d17497bff2871af68e
Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
                        <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; background : #F1F1F1;  padding: 20px;border-bottom:1px"> i have used the content-type:text/plain ,i have received the same result